# is there a way to count bytes over a specific time on a network connection?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

i.e 1 second, 5 seconds or however much time needed? curious how many bytes are going over certain connections. I've tried a bunch of different things and was wondering if you can do this without some kind of script and no installs needed
(on linux)

Comment: Do you mean to measure bandwidth?

Comment: Which operating system? Windows, Linux, UNIX, network OS on the switch,  all have different ways to get at their network interfaces.

Comment: sorry, yes on linux

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. But how to do this depends on your operating system. On linux you can look at `/proc/net/dev` for examle.

Comment: sorry i didn't add, yes on linux

Comment: how would i set it so that it measures it over a specific time?